# Where is /root/.keras/datasets/ in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm using colab notebook to download set like that:

```
_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
zip_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=_URL, fname="flower_photos.tgz",extract=True)
base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_file), 'flower_photos')
```

It shows dataset was downloaded in /root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos

However folder C:\Users\myUser.keras is empty.
Where did it go?

Comment: If you ran that code in colab, the file was downloaded in the remote server, not in your computer.

Answer (score 3):

The dataset is downloaded not to your machine but to Virtual Machine that is created when you create a new .ipynb file in Google Colab. Check the properties of your virtual machine using following commands in the Colab Notebook:

```
# Explore your VM
!ls -la /
# Find disk space and RAM space
!df -h
!free -m

#What OS is your VM using:
!cat /etc/os-release
```

And, check what all datasets you are having in your VM:

```
!ls  /root/.keras/datasets/
```

Answer (score 1):

An [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/importing-data-to-google-colab-the-clean-way-5ceef9e9e3c8) from Towards Data Science mentions that:

> There is one big issue with Google Colab, often discussed before, which is the storage of your data. Notebooks, for example, Jupyter notebooks, often use data files stored locally, on your computer. This is often done using a simple read_csv statement or comparable. But **Google Colaboratory is running in the Cloud**. **The Cloud’s local is not your local**. Therefore a read_csv statement will search for the file on Google’s side rather than on your side. And then it will not find it.

That is: Downloaded data is stored temporally at Cloud's local. If your colab notebook is disconnected then be sure such data is forever lost.

**How to fix that issue (lost of downloaded data)**: Use Google Drive along with Google Colaboratory notebooks. For more info about it read the mentioned article.